# Using MVC4 Custom Model to return Properties from other Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SimpleMemberShip. This is the default UserProfile Model:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a Model to get all user details from the Database across multiple Tables:

```
public class GetUserDetail
{
[Key]
[ReadOnly(true)]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }

public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string RoleName { get; set; }

[ReadOnly(true)]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public DateTime PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Currently is seems not to be possible. I am trying to fill a WebGrid for Admin access on my site. I am sure it can be done some how but maybe I am going about it the wrong way.

this is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
return View(context.GetUserDetails.ToList());
}
}
```

this is my Context Property:

```
// Account Model DB Set...
public DbSet<GetUserDetail> GetUserDetails { get; set; }
```

My WebGrid works if I specify the UserProfile as the model source:

```
@model List<myApp.Models.UserProfile>
```

but this does not work:

```
@model List<myApp.Models.GetUserDetail>
```

Is it possible to implement a custom Model to span multiple already implemented Tables?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with some help from Parv Sharma. Although this answer only put me on the right track, my actual solution is quite different.

I added a model:

```
public class UserProfileData
{
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }

public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public DateTime LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }

public DateTime PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added this code to the Controller:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
string sqlcommand = "SELECT UserProfile.UserId, UserProfile.UserName, webpages_Membership.CreateDate, webpages_Membership.LastPasswordFailureDate, webpages_Membership.PasswordChangedDate "
+ "FROM UserProfile CROSS JOIN webpages_Membership CROSS JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles "
+ "WHERE (UserProfile.UserId='1') ";

return View(context.Database.SqlQuery<UserProfileData>(sqlcommand).ToList());
}
```

In my View:

```
@model List<myApp.Models.UserProfileData>


@{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

I honestly expected this to be a little easier than this. My Issue is that the Tables in the Database for Roles do not have a model associated with them.

Maybe someone else can provide a better solution?

I still need to do some formatting and so on.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the 'WHERE (UserProfile.UserId='1')' and have a result returned with the right user data.

Comment: Changing WHERE (UserProfile.UserId='1') to WHERE (UserProfile.UserId=webpages_Membership.UserId) seems to work

Comment: SELECT UserProfile.UserId, UserProfile.UserName, webpages_Membership.CreateDate, webpages_Membership.LastPasswordFailureDate, webpages_Membership.PasswordChangedDate, webpages_Roles.RoleName
FROM webpages_Membership CROSS JOIN UserProfile CROSS JOIN  webpages_UsersInRoles CROSS JOIN webpages_Roles
WHERE (UserProfile.UserId=webpages_Membership.UserId) AND (webpages_Roles.RoleId=webpages_UsersInRoles.RoleId)
ORDER BY UserProfile.UserId,UserProfile.UserName,webpages_Membership.CreateDate,webpages_Membership.LastPasswordFailureDate,webpages_Membership.PasswordChangedDate, webpages_Roles.RoleName

Answer (score 3):

You will have to manually write queries against your dataContext to retrieve the entities and then send them to the view. Create a ViewModel that has all the properties you need

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var userDetailsViewModels = new UserDetailsViewModel
    return View(context.GetUserDetails
                       .Join(dataContext.SomeOtherTable, 
                             u => u.Ut, o => o.UserId, 
                             (u,o) => new UserDetailsViewModel { Name = u.Name, CreatinnDate = o.CreationDate }
                            )
               );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, looking up more on this now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intereted to learn about custom Model, you may want to take a look at ViewModel. [What is viewmodel in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)